# Adding numbers from Entry

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

Hello guys i'm making xamarin.forms app and have two inputs from entries and I need to add the numbers entered into a separate sums every time a button is pressed

```
                   x:Name="Player1"
                   Text="{Binding Player1.Text}"
                   Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"
                   FontSize="20"
                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                   LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
                   />
                <Entry Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" 
                    x:Name="scoreEntry1"
                    Keyboard="Numeric"
                    FontSize="25"
                    Placeholder="0"
                    HorizontalOptions="Fill" 
                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                    Margin="0,20,0,0"
                    />
                
                <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" 
                   x:Name="Player2"
                   Text="{Binding Player2.Text}"
                   Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"
                   FontSize="20"
                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                   LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
                   />
                <Entry Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" 
                    x:Name="scoreEntry2"
                    Keyboard="Numeric"
                    FontSize="25"
                    Placeholder="0"
                    HorizontalOptions="Fill" 
                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                    Margin="0,20,0,0"
                    />
<Grid>
                <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" 
                        Text="Next round" 
                        BackgroundColor="#26940F" 
                        TextColor="#FFFFFF"
                        Clicked="Next_round"
                        Command="{Binding ButtonNext}">
                </Button>
```

I've tried to do the calculation in the .cs but couldn't figure it out. Can someone help me?

Comment: Consider to remove all the styling code in UI components so readers can easier focus on your problem.

Answer (score 1):

first, don't use an event and a command on the button - pick one or the other

to add the numbers, do something like this

```
public void Next_round(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
  // use int.Parse if the number are ints, I'm assuming double
  var val1 = double.Parse(scoreEntry1.Text);
  var val2 = double.Parse(scoreEntry2.Text);
  
  // add them
  var sum = val1 + val2;
  
  // you haven't specified what you want to do with the result???
}
```

note that this is a very basic approach, and very brittle - it will break if the user enters in a string that is not a valid double.  To handle this you should add some exception handling (ie, a try/catch block), or use `TryParse` instead of just `Parse`.  Refer to the C# docs on either of these topics